# Как прокрутить страницу HTML в WebView до нужного места?

Tags: java, android

Есть страница HTML генерируемая в приложении.

При отображении ее в WebView нужно прокрутить ее до нужного абзаца.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Я в HTML/JS ничего не знаю и не умею, так что не ругайте, если где-то неточно написал.***

Пометьте абзац нужным id:

```
<p id="#info">Абзац</p>
```

В коде HTML создайте JS скрипт:

```
<script> 
function scrollAnchor(id) {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
</script>
```

Не забудьте включить JS для `WebView`

```
webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

И теперь вызывайте JS функцию:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:scrollAnchor(info)");
```

Comment: Просьба автору ответить, есть ли ошибка в ответе или все работает правильно?

Comment: Ответ смогу дать только послезавтра, т.к. срочно уехал.

Comment: Приятель попробовал: Результат: пока не работает. Может дело в вызове функции. Вначале я загружаю страницу, а потом вызываю функцию вот так:  wv.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/", inp_str, "text/html", "utf-8", null); } finally { }
        wv.loadUrl("javascript:scrollAnchor(15)");